# PHP Replacing white color in a transparent image

Tags: php, imagick

I am working on a php script that replaces the white color with a given one. This is the source image I'm working with:
[image]

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image]

The first script I tried:

```
    $im = imagecreatefrompng("taxi.png");

    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE); 
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 255, 255); 
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE); 

    imagealphablending( $im, false );
    imagesavealpha( $im, true );
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
```

This looked like this:
[image]

The second time I tried replacing the each pixel which resulted in having no tolerance, if a pixel was just 1 unit off it wouldn't get replaced.

```
function ReplaceColour($img, $r1, $g1, $b1, $r2, $g2, $b2)
{
    if(!imageistruecolor($img))
        imagepalettetotruecolor($img);
    $col1 = (($r1 & 0xFF) << 16) + (($g1 & 0xFF) << 8) + ($b1 & 0xFF);
    $col2 = (($r2 & 0xFF) << 16) + (($g2 & 0xFF) << 8) + ($b2 & 0xFF);

    $width = imagesx($img); 
    $height = imagesy($img);
    for($x=0; $x < $width; $x++)
        for($y=0; $y < $height; $y++)
        {
            $colrgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
            if($col1 !== $colrgb)
                continue; 
            imagesetpixel ($img, $x , $y , $col2);
        }   
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatefrompng("taxi.png");

ReplaceColour($im,245,245,245,255,0,0);

imagealphablending( $im, false );
imagesavealpha( $im, true );
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

[image]

At the moment I'm thinking about making a mask for the image and changing the mask's color on the fly, but the problem is that I would have to create it for every image I'm adding.

Comment: The real problem here is that you're not trying to replace "white" at all. If you look at the actual parts you want to recolor, there are tons of greys that are also found in, for instance, the windows and hubcaps (in fact, the hubcaps even contain white, but you're not recoloring that). So if you want to automate this, you're going to have to first _define_ what qualifies a color for replacement. E.g. is it white? if not, is it "close enough to being white"? if not, is its grey (above some threshold), and close enough a pixel you already said was white? etc. This is far from trivial.

Comment: In your case I would use a Image with solid background (white?) and make the car body transparent with some half transparent  gray shades. Then you can simply change the background behind the image. So it looks like youre changing the color of the hull :)